# Outlook 365 (online) is ignoring prefers-color-scheme: dark

Tags: css, html-email, email-templates

Outlook 365 in my Edge Browser (https://outlook.office.com/) Version 108.0.1462.54 (Official build) (64-bit) seems to ignore the prefers-color-scheme: dark value.

```
body{
    border:10px solid red;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {  
    body{
        border:10px solid blue;
    }
}
```

When I open the HTML file in the browser and emulate the dark mode, everything works fine.

Bests,
Yanick

Comment: It seems that Outlook on Windows does not support prefers-color-scheme. You can use https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=prefers-color-scheme to check what various email clients do understand and on what systems.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook.com (and the online version of Outlook 365) does support the `prefers-color-scheme` media query. (As mentioned in another comment, you can refer to [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media-prefers-color-scheme/).)

However, it’s important to note that the media query will always be based on your operating system color scheme preference. (Like macOS light or dark mode in the Preferences panel.) So even if you toggle Outlook.com’s dark or light mode icon, the styles your media query won‘t change. There are ways to achieve this using custom selectors and data attributes, like `[data-ogsb] .foo` which will only apply in dark mode. You can read more about this on this blog post I wrote: [Making Emails React to Outlook.com’s Dark Mode](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2021/emails-react-outlook-com-dark-mode/)

Another thing worth mentioning is that Outlook.com also don’t support the `<body>` element in itself. It will be converted to a `<div>` (but so will the corresponding styles, so it is not a problem in your condensed example).